# How to perform @mock in abstract class (not Inject Mock)

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

When I am trying to MOC the dependent classes (instance variables), it is not getting mocked for abstract class. But it is working for all other classes. Any idea how to resolve this issue. I know, I could cover this code from child classes. But I want to know whether it is possible to cover via abstract class or not. Also, I want to use Mockito to resolve it.
Currently, I am getting a NULL point exception on the following line because the mamApiDao is null & not getting mocked

OvpStatusResponse ovpStatusResponse = mamApiDao.updateOvpMetadataInMam(null, callbackMessage.getMediaId(), ovpStatus, publishMessage);

Abstract class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.qvc.qq.mamapimodel.model.mamapi.OvpStatus;
import com.qvc.qq.mamapimodel.model.mamapi.response.OvpStatusResponse;
import com.qvc.qq.mammessageprocessor.config.settings.MqMessageSettings;
import com.qvc.qq.mammessageprocessor.dao.MamApiDao;
import com.qvc.qq.mammessageprocessor.manager.ErrorMessageManager;
import com.qvc.qq.mammessageprocessor.model.CdnCallbackMessage;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.web.server.ResponseStatusException;
    
        public abstract class CallbackManager {
        
            private final MamApiDao mamApiDao;
        
            public CallbackManager( MamApiDao mamApiDao) {
                this.mamApiDao = mamApiDao;
            }
           
        
            public void processCallback(CdnCallbackMessage callbackMessage, int retries, OvpStatus ovpStatus, String publishMessage) {
                // some code 
                
                //mamApiDao is NULL, it is not getting mocked
               OvpStatusResponse ovpStatusResponse = mamApiDao.updateOvpMetadataInMam(null, callbackMessage.getMediaId(), ovpStatus, publishMessage);
                
                // some code 
        
            }
            
        }
```

Test Class

```
import com.qvc.qq.mamapimodel.model.mamapi.OvpStatus;
import com.qvc.qq.mamapimodel.model.mamapi.response.OvpStatusResponse;
import com.qvc.qq.mammessageprocessor.config.settings.MqMessageSettings;
import com.qvc.qq.mammessageprocessor.dao.MamApiDao;
import com.qvc.qq.mammessageprocessor.dao.MqMessagingDao;
import com.qvc.qq.mammessageprocessor.model.CdnCallbackMessage;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyString;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.isNull;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
public class CallbackManagerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    CallbackManager callbackManager = Mockito.mock(CallbackManager.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);

    @Mock
    MamApiDao mamApiDao;
    
    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
      
    }
    
     @Test
    public void processCallbackTest() {
        when(mamApiDao.updateOvpMetadataInMam(any(), anyString(), any(), anyString())).thenReturn(new OvpStatusResponse());
        callbackManager.processCallback(cdnCallbackMessage, 1, OvpStatus.ACTIVE, "published");
        verify(mamApiDao, times(1)).updateOvpMetadataInMam(any(), anyString(), any(), anyString());

    }
}
```

Enum Class

```
public enum OvpStatus {
    SUBMITTED("SUBMITTED"),
    ACTIVE("ACTIVE"),
    INACTIVE("INACTIVE"),
    ERROR("ERROR"),
    NONE("NONE");

    private String value;

    private OvpStatus(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Dao class

```
import com.qvc.qq.mamapimodel.model.mamapi.OvpStatus;

    import com.qvc.qq.mamapimodel.model.mamapi.response.OvpStatusResponse;
    import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    
    @Slf4j
    @Component
    public class MamApiDao {
          
    
        public OvpStatusResponse updateOvpMetadataInMam(String mamId, String ovpId, OvpStatus status, String publishMessage) {
    
    
            OvpStatusResponse ovpStatusResponse = new OvpStatusResponse();
            ovpStatusResponse.setId(1);
            ovpStatusResponse.setStatus("");
            return ovpStatusResponse;
        }
    }
```

Test Dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Looks like `@InjectMocks` is not processed because you have field initializer. I'm pretty sure what you want is not supported. You not supposed to test mocked classes.

Comment: Shouldn't the @Mock annotation suppose to work. So that the following code will return an object. I mean it does work for all the other classes, or is it something specific with abstract class. 
Currently, I am getting a NULL point exception on the following line because the mamApiDao is null & not getting mocked
 when(mamApiDao.updateOvpMetadataInMam(any(), anyString(), any(), anyString())).thenReturn(new OvpStatusResponse());

Comment: I was unable to reproduce problem. Can you provide Minimal, Reproducible Example?

Comment: Yea, I will put together something. Thank you for trying

Comment: @talex Just added more code snippets to the original question

Answer (score 0):

can you try like the below one?

```
public class CallbackManagerTest {

@InjectMocks
CallbackManager callbackManager = Mockito.mock(CallbackManager.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS);

@MockBean
private MamApiDao mamApiDao;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
  
}

//do something
```

Comment: Yea, tried that. But null exception occurred when I code reached the following line. MaapiDao was null. when(mamApiDao.updateOvpMetadataInMam(any()

Comment: Did you tested your mamApiDao by running it manually from CallbackManager class?

Comment: yea.. The functional test is already done.